# How to get one Igx-column value into another column

Tags: angular, infragistics, ignite-ui-angular, igx-grid

I am using Infragistics [grid](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/grid/grid). I have several columns, and I am trying to access the value of the first column inside the last one.

I created a variable inside `IgxColumnComponent`, however when I access it from another `IgxColumnComponent` I get [object][object]

Object is like bellow

```html
<igx-column #docid field="documentId" header="Document Id" [filterable]="true" dataType="string" style="font-size:20px">

</igx-column>

<igx-column field="source" header="Source" [filterable]="true" dataType="string" style="font-size:10px">
    <ng-template igxCell let-cell="cell">
        <div *ngIf="cell.value==2">
            <span>
                {{docid}}
                <img src="../../assets/icons/po-ack-Icon.png" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</igx-column>
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible code example as a starting point, for example, an Angular project in https://stackblitz.com/. It's then way easier to help you. Read more about it at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another `IgxColumnComponent`’s field value can be accessed from the `IgxCell`’s `rowData`
property:

```html
<igx-column field="source"header="Source" [filterable]="true"
            dataType="string" style="font-size:10px">
  <ng-template igxCell let-cell="cell">
    <div *ngIf="cell.rowData.DocumentId==2">
      <span>
        {{cell.rowData.DocumentId}}
      </span>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</igx-column>
```

Here is a [stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/access-value-from-another-column?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgrid%2Fgrid-sorting-sample%2Fgrid-sorting-sample.component.html) that demonstrates this.

Additionally, all the `IgxCell`’s properties are listed in the Infragistics documentation [here](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/typescript/latest/classes/igxcell.html) and more about `IgxColumnComponent` can be found [here](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/typescript/latest/classes/igxcolumncomponent.html).